# WSO2AM strange errors after successful startup

Tags: java, tomcat, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed a fresh version of WSO2AM 3.2.0 by just extracting the downloaded ZIP file to `/opt/wso2am/wso2am-3.2.0/`. I have also set up two databases (db_am and db_shared) and I am using those in the file `deployment.toml` as described in the documentation. Then I'm starting  the application by just executing the `wso2server.sh` script. It starts up just fine and the following lines appear, telling me that the application has started successfully.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-10-26 15:59:14,710]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Server           :  WSO2 API Manager-3.2.0                                
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-10-26 15:59:14,717]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - WSO2 Carbon started in 53 sec                                             
TID: [-1] [] [2020-10-26 15:59:14,776]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user admin connected
```

But right after that it gives me the following errors:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-10-26 15:59:15,600] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q0MHWf0UB+WyZD03ES/pzA=="  
TID: [-1234] [internal/data/v1] [2020-10-26 15:59:15,903] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q0MHWf0UB+WyZD03ES/pzA=="
TID: [-1234] [internal/data/v1] [2020-10-26 15:59:15,903] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q0MHWf0UB+WyZD03ES/pzA=="
TID: [-1234] [internal/data/v1] [2020-10-26 15:59:15,932] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q0MHWf0UB+WyZD03ES/pzA=="
TID: [-1234] [internal/data/v1] [2020-10-26 15:59:15,933] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q0MHWf0UB+WyZD03ES/pzA=="
TID: [-1234] [internal/data/v1] [2020-10-26 15:59:15,933] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q0MHWf0UB+WyZD03ES/pzA=="
TID: [-1] [] [2020-10-26 15:59:15,651] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} - Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://<the servers local ip>:9711. org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://<the servers local ip>:9711.                                            
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:145)                                                             
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59)                                                                  
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Error while trying to login to data receiver :/<the servers local ip>:9711                                            
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:50)                                                                             
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:139)                                                             
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.AuthenticationException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Those lines then repeat indefinitely. I really don't understand where those errors are coming from.

- The string from the first few errors looks like a password or a token but I have not set this string anywhere in the config.
- The other errors, telling me about borrowing some client don't make any more sense to me

Where do these errors come from and how could I fix them or even find out what is causing them?

Comment: did you configure this value(q0MHWf0UB+WyZD03ES/pzA==) somewhere? I think there is an issue with the database. Can you check given DB configs are correct?

Comment: No, I did not configure this value and searching for this string in the AM directory also yields nothing (except being mentioned in logfiles, of course).

Comment: try telnet to 9611 and 9711 if it is working there is no issue with TM. If so this could be an issue with your UM DB. You can use the default DB configs and confirm this.

Comment: I can neither connect to 9611 nor 9711 with telnet. So I will try to reset the database and try again. Starting the AM with the default h2 databases worked, so I guess there really must be something wrong with the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the database issue Check whether your database server is up and running and your database configs are correctly configured in deployment.toml(username, password, URL, port) and you have run the correct MySQL scripts to your databases as in the docs. (Also don't forget to include the JDBC driver)

ex: deployment.toml configs

```
[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shared_db?useSSL=false"
username = "root"
password = "admin"
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding `useSSL=false` indeed made it work. Appearently there is something wrong with the SSL configuration.

Comment: Before start, the server checks whether is some other thing is running on 9611 and 9711 ports. if those processes are no need, as a quick solution, you can kill the processes of those ports before running the APIM.    `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:9611)`

Answer (score 1):

Check whether port 9711 is opened on a different network interface instead of your . You can verify this by executing the following command.

```
   sudo lsof -i -P -n
```

If it is open to another network interface then close that port and
then start the APIM server again.

Or else you can change the APIM configs to configure a new port.

```
[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<server_ip>:<port>","tcp://<server_ip>:<port>"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<server_ip>:<port>","ssl://<server_ip>:<port>"]
type = "failover"
```

An example configuration is given below.

```
[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
type = "failover"
```

Comment: No, it is just once I start the AM that `lsof -i -P -n | grep 9711` returns: `java    30754         api  532u  IPv4 447739      0t0  TCP *:9711 (LISTEN)`

Comment: Using the suggested configuration makes the SSL related errors disappear but still leaves me with a lot of datbase related errors.